# How to Filter-out Mid Spatial Frequencies?

Tags: optics, frequency, interference, interferometry, image-processing

In my Twyman-Green interferometer, I am testing a microscope obejective. The reference spherical mirror introduces Mid Spatial Frequencies (MSFs), whose effect on the wavefront measurements I'm currently trying to investigate. I was looking through some papers and found out MSFs usually span the frequency range from $\frac{10}{D}$ up to $\frac{1000}{D}$, where $D$ is the diameter of the spherical mirror - in my case $3mm$. I decided to use a Wiener filter to remove the frequencies. In my Python script I used scipy's scipy.signal.wiener() function, where I only needed to provide the image to be filtered and specify the window size for the filter. After some trial and error, I found out a window size of 30px does the job and I got very promising results, where the diameter of my interferogram is 576px, a single pixel being $5.86\mu m$.

My question is: Is there a way to calculate the window size beforehand and how could I do that?